# Using Open layer for rendering large PNG images, getting canvas Area exceeds issue in Ios devices

Tags: angular, iphone, canvas, safari, openlayers

We are using ImageLayer, which is a large custom PNG. The implementation works fine in desktop and all browsers but throws error iniPhone devices.

warning message we are getting is: **canvas area exceeds the maximum limit (width * height > 16777216)**

Seems like a issue with safari  Refernce : https://pqina.nl/blog/canvas-area-exceeds-the-maximum-limit/

is there any work around for this.

i even tried with a reduced image size

have tried downgrading ol version to 7.2.2 still doesn't work

Comment: If you are using OpenLayers 7.3.0 you will need to revert to the previous version.  See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14555

Comment: @Samuel Liew The "duplicate" does not use a PNG.  This is a different issue.

Comment: @Mike have downgraded and tried. didnt work

Comment: Does the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html or https://openlayers.org/en/v7.2.2/examples/reprojection-image.html work on your device?  If that works there may be something else in your code adding to canvas use.

Comment: they provided  examples are very small image . so works.. what i need to work with very large size images.

Comment: You could split the image into tiles as in https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-flag-canvas-tiles-292mps?file=/main.js